# Can't access IIS website from local IP

Tags: asp.net, iis, networking

I have a .Net service hosted on IIS. The service was accessible from IP:Port/Service.asmx, until recently when I couldn't access it from IP or System name again but only from Localhost:port/Service.asmx. I have pinged the server and it is replying. I have also confirmed that the local ip is listening on port 80. Really I don't know what is wrong, I have been on this for so long.

Comment: If you use F12 developer tools in a browser, say chrome, and type the IP into the browser, how does the server respond?

Comment: It continues loading and just shows could not send response data. The XXX.XX.XX.XX page isn’t working

XXX.XX.XX.XX didn’t send any data.

Comment: What's the site binding in IIS Manager?

Answer (score 0):

That's a hard one.  Things I'd try:

1. Rebooting system.
2. Set a breakpoint at the earliest part of the request pipeline to verify whether the request is making it into your .Net code
3. Make a browser request via IP for a static file like an image.  Is that served? That lets you see if the server will respond for a request that likely isn't going through Asp.Net.

Comment: I tried telnet the ip on port 80 outside of the server and the connection could not be opened

Comment: But you stated "I have also confirmed that the local ip is listening on port 80"  How can it be listening if the port won't allow itself to be opened?

Comment: PS C:\Users\sp_admin>  netstat -an | where{$_.Contains("80")}
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8081           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:80           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8000         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    172.31.28.62:80        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    172.31.28.62:8000      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    172.31.28.62:8080      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

Comment: Then I'd setup a brand new site in IIS and put one image at the root and see if I could get that bare bones new site to serve the image via the IP address because something doesn't add up.

Comment: still the same thing the image is served with http://localhost/iis-85.png but can't be accessed with http://172.31.28.62/iis-85.png

Comment: It looks like it's on port 80 on the loop back IP i.e. 127.0.0.1:80  but on port 8080 on the machine IP i.e. 172.31.28.62:8080 based on the netstat info.  so you'd need to get the image at 172.31.28.62:8080/iis-85.png

Comment: Update: A request to the service gives this:Error

The requested URL can not be retrieved

Unable to connect to remote webserver.

Comment: On your new bare bones site with the one image, when you tried to request the image via the browser on port 8080 like this: 172.31.28.62:8080/iis-85.png  did it work?

Comment: No it didn't but accessing the web service with the system name/service.asmx seems to be hitting a 500 internal server error. Please how do I set iis to show a more detailed error

Comment: If the 500 is coming IIS, then check the system's event logs.  If it's coming from your code then do #2 on my original trouble shooting list in my answer.